# How can i do this layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Anyone has idea how can i do this gridview?

[image]

I think its a imageview with a background rounded in top, but the bottom of image? I dont have idea.

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bootstrapbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/panel_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:background="#686868">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#686868">

        <com.etsy.android.grid.util.DynamicHeightImageView
            android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@drawable/shadow" />

        <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
            android:id="@+id/btnDeletePhoto"
            bootstrapbutton:bb_size="small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            bootstrapbutton:bb_icon_right="fa-trash-o"
            bootstrapbutton:bb_type="danger"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|right"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/grid_item_image"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_card"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <com.etsy.android.grid.util.DynamicHeightTextView
                android:id="@+id/photoDesc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Descrpciooon blablabla"
                android:textColor="#9A9A9A"
                android:maxLength="15"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

This is my result:

[image]

I need something xml to do the similar bottom of my example.
Anyone has a example like this? I tried to do with a card-ui xml layout but it isnt like this.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide  more information on "but the bottom of image" ?

Comment: Yes, i want to do anything like as a white border with text in my image example.I will put a image with my result

Comment: You need rounded corners for all the sides . right?

Comment: Yes, and the shadow of bottom of view.

Comment: Ok. See my answer. Set your own background color for the bottom layout

Comment: this makes me remember a similar page: https://developer.android.com/design/get-started/ui-overview.html#app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create two `Layout` with rounded corners background . The top layout will have rounded corner only in top and bottom layout only in bottom corner. Add all the inner views(Image and text) inside the top layout. 
The `bottom layout` background `color` should match the main `GridView layout` , so that you will get the shadow feeling.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_item_bg">
 </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_border"></LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Create a grid_item_bg drawable as

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="@color/White"></solid>
  <corners android:topRightRadius="2dp" android:topLeftRadius="2dp"></corners>
</shape>
```

And bottom drawable as

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
 <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp" android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"></corners>
 <gradient android:startColor="@color/DimGray" android:endColor="@color/DimGray"></gradient>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create activity layout file as **`GridView`** with the padding and spacing required and `android:numColumns="2"`

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:numColumns="2">
</GridView>
```

Create a **`shape`** for the rounded corners.

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

Create the image and title layout as **`LinearLayout`** with `android:orientation="vertical"` and `android:background="@drawable/shape"`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/shape">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ImageView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example, it will solve your problem.

http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/pinterest-like-adapterview/